# ReactNative Eject Explained

Tags: react-native

I literally started reading about ReactNative an hour ago and am reading this git readme https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/README.md

Next I googled about it and found this link which seem to be explaining it but not to me novice in web, react, or react-native
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md

Can someone explain to me as if I am 2 years old what is the meaning of eject?  I keep hearing term "ejected project" but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Summary

If you created an app using `create-react-native-app MyApp`, ejecting your app gets your app to be the same as if you created your project using `react-native init MyApp`

**aka**

`create-react-native-app MyApp` > make changes to app > eject app

is roughly equivalent to

`react-native init MyApp` > make changes to app

### More Details

What's the difference between `create-react-native-app MyApp` and `react-native init MyApp`?

### Quick start vs. Full scale development

The philosophy behind create-react-native-app is:

> - **Minimal "Time to Hello World"**: Create React Native App should reduce the setup time it takes to try building a mobile app to the absolute minimum, ideally on par with React web development (especially as seen with Create React App).
> - **Develop on Your Device**: It should be easy to develop on a physical device when you want to test how your app feels and responds to inputs.
> - **One Build Tool**: If you just want to get started with React Native, you shouldn't need to install Xcode, Android Studio, NDKs, or mess with environment variables.
> - **No Lock-In**: You can always "eject" to your own build setup if you need to write custom native code or modify how your app is built.

Essentially, create-react-native-app lets you get up and running quickly **without having to a do a lot of (or any) configuration**. In order to do this, it hides a lot of details from you.

If you want to create a serious app, you need to set up a real development environment. You can do this from scratch by running `react-native init <project-name>`. If you started with a react native project using create-react-native-app, you can get to this same place by "ejecting" your app

More details from the official documentation about getting started with React Native can be found [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: When i eject my react-native app to react-native (not to Expo kit), it shows ejected succesfully and afterwards it shows a error 'Failed at <Projectnane>  3.1 eject script'.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that when you run the "create-react-native-app" (or "expo init" now) you are basically adding the Expo library on top of React Native.

I think the main reason for using Expo is to get your app up and running quickly. I think the main reason to eject is that eventually you might need to do more complicated customization with native code and need more control, etc. Here is a better explanation of Expo vs React Native CLI to bootstrap your app:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/expo-vs-react-native-cli-a-guide-to-bootstrapping-new-react-native-apps-6f0fcafee58f

When you eject you are returning to the same state as if you did not use Expo to setup your app (native ios/android projects will be generated, etc.)

Here are a few other links that helped me understand:
http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/environment

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/

Comment: not only that, expo solves a huge problem: building and running the app on both platforms android and ios