# rn-nodeify for the React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, cryptography

Steps to reproduce:

`create-react-native-app proj && cd proj && npm i`

Installing package that is using crypto. Performing steps listed at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-crypto :

```
npm i -S react-native-crypto && npm i -S react-native-randombytes
react-native link react-native-randombytes
```

Got a warning for react-native link failure, however after the following hack crypto dependancy is no longer a problem:

```
npm i --save-dev tradle/rn-nodeify
./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install
```

Adding `import './shim.js'` into the App.js

`yarn run ios`

Got a problem like here: https://github.com/mvayngrib/react-native-randombytes/issues/13

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNRandomBytes.seed')

I can't update npm and node due to some of the used package restrictions

MacOS 10.12, Node 8.0.0, npm 5.0

EDIT:

RNRandomBytes are initialized as `let RNRandomBytes = require('react-native').NativeModules.RNRandomBytes`

`init` is the first place where RNRandomBytes is accessed in react-native-randombytes imported from react-native-crypto imported from twitter nacl

EDIT2: After creating project via `react-native init` linking phase completed successfully:

```
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-randombytes android dependency 
rnpm-install info Android module react-native-randombytes has been successfully linked 
rnpm-install info Linking react-native-randombytes ios dependency 
rnpm-install info iOS module react-native-randombytes has been successfully linked
```

`import './shim.js'` for this sample project is in the index.js instead of App.js

But the error was the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RNRandomBytes` variable is not defined, because it should be exported by a native module, and you haven't linked the module.

The `react-native link` step fails, because you've initialised your project using `create-react-native-app`, which is based on Expo, and does not allow linking custom native dependencies.

If you want to use this library (or other React Native libraries with native dependencies) you'll need to either eject from the Expo app, or initialise your project with `react-native init`.

You can read more about the difference between `create-react-native-app` and `react-native init` here: [whats the real diff between "create-react-native-app myproject" and "react-native init myproject"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782536/whats-the-real-diff-between-create-react-native-app-myproject-and-react-nativ/45783307#45783307).

Comment: Thanks you for a very detailed explanation! I'll check if it will work for me right now

Comment: I've created a sample project with `react-native init` (linking doesn't fail anymore) and added shim.js to the index.js, but the error is still there. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Update. I tried on another mac and it worked. Looks like node installation was broken on this one. Thank you again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I am also facing the same error but i want to solve it on my machine I don't have another machine

Comment: @jevakallio is there a way to use node std libs like 'crypto' with expo without having to eject?