# Impossible to make react native router flux sample project work with latest versions of dependencies

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to make [this sample project](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/tree/master/examples/redux/android) to work with latest dependencies versions.

I created a repo with my attempt : https://github.com/Sharcoux/redux.git

I want to be able to use react-native 0.59, but when I tried, I got [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299138/could-not-get-unknown-property-mergeresourcesprovider-for-object-of-type-com) and was requested to upgrade gradle version.

After upgrading gradle, I'm able to build the project, but I get on my phone:

`Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a metro server...`

Of course, I have the server running with no error: `Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.` **Edit:** (The server starts automatically with `react-native run-android`, but I restarted it with `yarn start` just to be sure).

If I try to reload, I get a new error:

`Could not connect to development server`

I already tried to go to `Dev settings -> Debug server host & port for device` and set the `192.168.<local ip of my laptop>:8081`

The project used to work fine before upgrading the dependencies. What could cause this?

Maybe someone very generous could:

```
git clone https://github.com/Sharcoux/redux.git
cd redux
yarn install
npx react-native run-android
```

And see if they can make it work?

Comment: run npm start in your project

Comment: I already did. This starts the Metro Bundler server, and as I said, it is up and running: `Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.`.
If you don't mind, could you try to clone the sample repo https://github.com/Sharcoux/redux.git and see if it works for you maybe?

Comment: define routes screen in router

Comment: I'm sorry in advanced if my question is stupid, but what do you mean exactly? What am I supposed to do concretely? (Thanks a lot for your help anyway)

Comment: Any idea what caused the down vote btw?

Comment: Could you try the changes I did here in this commit? https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/commit/cd74da5f28f3a0d3c33be781a7f07463ace6b00f I believe some of those are still relevant for this sort of errors.

Comment: I'll try that ASAP and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: do you experience the same problems when starting a new project with `react-native init`? did you try `react-native run --reset-cache`? Are you running an emulator or real device? If this is not related to this specific project, you may want to try [the common solutions for this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows) 

Instead if it is related to the dependencies, the question is which dependency is causing the issue so that we can better understand what is wrong

Comment: @DavisZ.Cabral Ok, back to the problem, I'm not sure about what you expect me to do. Moreover, your PR has already been merged into RNRF apparently, so I guess I do have your changes into my project, don't I?

Comment: Sorry about the late answer - yes - but the related changes to gradle sometime are required. Android development with react-native is a bit painful yet. Glad someone else found the fix for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I cloned your Github project same you;

```
git clone https://github.com/Sharcoux/redux.git
cd redux
npm i --save 
react-native run-android
```

I took similar error then I delete ios and android files after I run, [about eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251746/reactnative-eject-explained)

```
react-native eject
```

again run

```
npm i --save / npm install -S

react-native run-android
```

I took again an error Count not found react-native-gesture-handler ...

```
npm i react-native-gesture-handler --save
```

The done project worked but I still a problem

project files in `app.js`

> reduxifyNavigator is deprecated in
>   react-navigation-redux-helpers@3.0.0! Please use createReduxContainer
>   instead.

Replacing every `reduxifyNavigator` occurences by `createReduxContainer` leads to the following error: `navStateSelector is not a function`.

Thanks to [this post](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-redux-helpers/issues/76), you can notice that `react-navigation-redux-helpers` introduced some [breaking changes](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-redux-helpers/releases/tag/3.0.0) in their last upgrade. The order of the parameters in `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware` has changed and the key is now optional.

Removing the `'root'` key in `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware` finishes to solve the problem.

Comment: Not bad. let me investigate that last issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I searching too. İf I will find I can add  :)

Comment: Ok. So, basically, is you replace `reduxifyNavigator` by `createReduxContainer` everywhere inside `app.js`, and `Router` by `ReduxNavigator` line 36, and then remove `navigator={ReduxNavigator}` line 43, the app will start. Which is great... Except that the navigation doesn't work... Which sucks.

Comment: Ok I got it to work ! :)
The steps: replace `reduxifyNavigator` by `createReduxContainer`. Remove the first parameter `root` in `createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware` line 31, and boom ! It works